# Vendor Directory Creating duplicate conflicted directories

Tags: go, govendor

I updated my version of go from 1.13 --> 1.15 and now I am getting some errors in my code that appear to be related to the code in the vendor directory not appearing like the actually imported code.  The upgrade might not be the root cause but it does seem to be coorelated.

I am not an expert on the vendor directory so could be missing something obvious.  I am getting quite a few errors like this now.

Error:

```
~/Documents/GoLang/src/github.com/mornindew/domain_account/vendor/cloud.google.com/go/logging/apiv2/config_client.go:113:3: cannot use conn (type *"google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConn) as type *"github.com/mornindew/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConn in field value
```

It appears that it is not recognizing the "ClientConn" in the vendor directory as the same one that is in the $GOPATH/src.  I am not explicitally putting any of the go source files in the vendor directory but they end up there anyways.

Any help on how to avoid this would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing ends up in the vendor directory automatically, you must specifically put things there. If you are not using `vendor/`, it should not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I should have tried this but clearing out my entire Vendor directory seemed to fix the issue.  Seems like a hack solution but appears to have worked.